# Enable CORS when running AWS SAM CLI locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, aws-sam-cli

Whenever I try to access serverless lambda function via POST through the browser I get the error

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No >'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

When it is a `/GET` it works fine I have read it is because it is not sending pre flight request. When I change it to `POST` this is when it fails.

The command I am running:

`sam local start-api`

And my template.yaml is:

```
...

Resources:
    PropertiesFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: target/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
            Handler: com.aws.PropertiesHandler::handleRequest
            Runtime: java8
            Events:
                PropertiesApi:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /properties
                        Method: post

...
```

How can I enable CORS on these endpoints?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error and I have already fixed it in 3 steps. (AWS Lambda in Java8, SAM CLI v0.37.0)

1. Add options for your header:

```
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.put("X-Custom-Header", "application/json");
    headers.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.put("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    headers.put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
```

2. Add Option Cors into template.yaml

```
    Globals:
      Function:
        Timeout: 20
      Api:
        Cors:
          AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,OPTIONS'"
          AllowHeaders: "'content-type'"
          AllowOrigin: "'*'"
          AllowCredentials: "'*'"
```

3. Update properties resource function in template.yaml

```
          Events:
            HelloWorld:
              Type: Api 
              Properties:
                # Path: /hello
                # Method: get
                Path: "/{proxy+}"
                Method: ANY
```

Comment: you saved my day. My YAML was almost the same but in lamda I was missing the header so after adding the header it works for me.

Answer (score 6):

First, you will need to add the following section in the template.yml to enable cors in the API gateway:

```yaml
Globals:
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'content-type'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      AllowCredentials: "'*'"
```

Then in your lambda function response

```java
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", requestContext.getHeaderString("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!  Was having some trouble finding an answer to this yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to get around this for local testing by explicitly adding the following headers to your response, in your handler function:

```
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

You can use an environment variable that only adds the headers if you're running locally.

Here's a simple Python example from a handler function I have:

```
   if not all(field in values for field in required_fields):
    response = {
        'statusCode': 400,
        'body': json.dumps(
            {
                'message': 'Required data missing from request body'
            }
        )        
    }
    # explicitly add CORs headers for local testing
    response['headers'] = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
    return response
```

This is only suitable for local testing, when you deploy to an API Gateway CORs is handled by configuration on the API Gateway.

This solution worked for me until I also added authorization to the API, with a Cognito user pool, which I'm currently trying to work through.

Here's a similar post on the issue:
[How to Enable CORS for an AWS API Gateway Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539161/how-to-enable-cors-for-an-aws-api-gateway-resource?rq=1)

[Here's reference to it in the official AWS documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format)

Comment: Did you ever have any luck after adding the auth - I'm at the same point unfortunately.

Comment: I am also at the point of adding the auth and I'm getting CORS errors.  Did you ever have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your serverless template file if you are using SAM

```
"Globals": {
    "Api": {
      "Cors": {
        "AllowMethods": "'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE'",
        "AllowHeaders": "'content-type'",
        "AllowOrigin": "'*'"
      }
    }
}
```